# ng serve or ng build --prod doesn't generate dist folder in angular 4 application

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I build an angular 4 app, and build it trough angular-cli 1.0.4 with the command `ng build --prod`. So here I could not get a *dist* folder out of this to deploy in Microsoft azure. What should I do to get the *dist* folder after `ng build --prod` is done? Can someone help me with a better solution to publish my app to a server?

Comment: What is the output of the `ng build --prod` command? Do you have write permissions on the project folder?

Comment: Additionally, have you already tried updating your cli? The current version is `"@angular/cli": "^1.2.3"`. Also note that every time you do `ng build`or `ng serve`, the dist path is cleared. This can be turned off by providing `--no-delete-output-path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng build --env=prod` instead of `ng build --prod` and see if that helps. When I made a brand new project and ran `ng build --prod`, I got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'` error. But when I ran `ng build --env=prod` dist was generated fine.

Comment: I got the dist folder into the app. Thank you Ram.

Comment: I believe this error was fixed in Angular CLI 1.2.4.

Comment: Thanks for the info @yakov-fain. I was using 1.2.0.

Comment: @YakovFain, upgrading to 1.2.4 did not fix that error. Do you know of an angular-cli issue I can keep track of?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue on github. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7125